# Best practice to save user input for the duration of session Drupal 8

Tags: php, session, drupal-8

I am working on a website with Drupal8. I am wondering what's a good practice to store user-specific data that is important for the length of the session. As an example, let's say a user is a student in a school and is taking different classes/courses. After login the user chooses one of the courses and then only gets to see all the content/other students/... of this particular course.

The easiest solution I can think of is just storing the data in the $_SESSION object. But then all the views in drupal would have to read the data from this object and as far as I know this was possible in Drupal7 with custom php code, but not anymore in Drupal8 views.

Also additionally, if I'd like to store the user's default preference permanently, I could create a custom content type 'user_config_data' or something like this, where I store information that is important for the current session (and needs to be accessed in each view etc) and also a value for a default choice (i.e. the course the user wants to see as default after login)

The latter could probably also be achieved via cookies?!

Something else I did not think of ?

Is any of the approaches more/less advantageous in terms of performance, good coding practice, modifiability ? Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PrivateTempStore](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21PrivateTempStore.php/class/PrivateTempStore/8.2.x) is what you're looking for. You can use it to store data per user over the entire session.

You can use it like this

```
$tempStoreService = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore');

// Set a variable in the tempstore
$tempStoreService->set('user_data', $data);

// Get a variable from the tempstore
$userData = $tempStoreService->get('user_data');
```

This works over the entire session of a user. In case you need to share data between users you can use the [SharedTempStore](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21SharedTempStore.php/class/SharedTempStore/8.2.x)

Comment: But then how would I read from tempstore to make the variable available in a view ?

Answer (score 0):

I did more reading on that and I am now using `$tempStoreService` as shown by VJamie. To make the argument available in a Drupal 8 view I created a custom module to implement hook_views_pre_view() and add my value as an argument to the view. Then I am using a contextual filter in the view to make sure the argument is used. However, the preview for the view works nicely, but on the real page the view gets cached and the output is the same no matter what argument I give. Only when disabling caching for the entire view it works. Is this a standard approach or is there a different solution to the caching problem with contextual filters ?